# AccessibilityTraits StartsMedia is not working

Tags: ios, react-native, accessibility, voiceover

I'm trying to force VoiceOver to stop when an audio component is tapped on on iOS mobile. All I see in the documentation is a statement and theoretical explanation that  `accessibilityTraits StartsMedia` does this, but could not find any real implementation. Is it correct to set `accessibilityTraits={RX.Types.AccessibilityTrait.StartsMedia}` property on the `RX.View` ?

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiaccessibility/uiaccessibilitytraits/1620173-startsmediasession sounds like it's pretty clear, although it talks about `startsMediaSession`, not `StartsMedia`, but perhaps the OP meant startsMediaSession.

> Use this trait to silence the audio output of an assistive technology, such as VoiceOver, during a media session that should not be interrupted. For example, you might use this trait to silence VoiceOver speech while the user is recording audio.

Another explanation is on [Deque's site](https://www.deque.com/blog/ios-traits/).

> When a VoiceOver user double taps the screen on a button, the button is clicked, and the label of the button repeated to the user.  This would obviously be frustrating if the purpose of the button were to play a sound!  Especially a short sound.  Interrupting the first few seconds of Yellow Submarine isn’t the end of the world, but what if a user is checking out new alert sounds?  The sound may be shorter than the announcement!  This would be highly frustrating.  Applying this trait to a button stops this behavior, canceling any announcement, allowing sounds played as a result of interaction with the control to be heard.